# 400 when passing url in @PathVariable to Spring MVC controller method

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to pass a url in to a Spring MVC controller method in a `@PathVariable` but am getting a `400` http response code, and the request is rejected before it reaches the controller method.

My request is being issued as:

```
curl 'https://127.0.0.1:8443//myapi/page/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.co.uk%2Ffolder%2Fpage_n0/info' -k -w "\nResponse code: %{http_code}\n"
```

The controller method, and `UTF-8` filter, is:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean()
{
    CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    filter.setForceEncoding(true);
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
}
@RequestMapping(value = {"/myapi/page/{url}/info"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("url") String webPage)
{
    ResponseEntity<?> results = new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(HttpStatus.OK);
    // Do something here
    return results;
}
```

I am using Tomcat 8.5.5, and nothing is present in the log files (logging has been set at DEBUG level) except for the following entry in `localhost_access_log.2016-10-04.txt`:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2016:09:04:24 +0100] "GET //myapi/page/http%/info HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

In my test code, the url being passed into is being encoded using `URLEncoder.encode()`, so should be being encoded correctly.

In the remote debugger, I can see that the `CharacterEncodingFilter` registration code above is being entered so the filter should be being registered.

I have also added`URIEncoding="UTF-8"` to each of the Connectors in the `server.xml` file in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf`.

I am going round in circles with this and keep on thinking there's something obvious I'm missing. I've never had any issues using a `@PathVariable` before so I presume I'm encountering some sort of encoding issue, probably relating to the `%` sign.

I'd be grateful for any help with this!

Update:

I think the issue is that Spring, inside `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping` and `UriUtils`, is decoding the entire url, including the `@PathVariable` portion. It then cannot find a request mapping for the decoded url which is unsurprising since the decoded url includes the decoded url in the `@PathVariable`. I need to find some way of telling Spring not to decode the `application/x-www.form-urlencoded` portion of the url.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have found that the %2F character (/) in the encoded url is causing issues, possibly because Spring is getting confused between the %2F character in the encoded url and the "/" path separator in the main url being called.